# CMake multiple errors when include boost/beast/http.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-asio, boost-beast

I'm trying to build my project that uses boost beast library with cmake.
When I use only boost asio library everything builds okay. But when I add boost/beast/http.hpp header when cmake gives a huge amount of errors.

CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(ConsoleChat.Server)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

find_package(Boost 1.75.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)

add_definitions(-DBOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(ConsoleChat.Server main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ConsoleChat.Server ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Code file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>

namespace net = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        if (argc != 3)
        {
            std::cout <<
                "Usage: websocket-chat-multi <address> <port>\n" <<
                "Example:\n" <<
                "    websocket-chat-server 0.0.0.0 8080\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        auto const address = net::ip::address::from_string(argv[1]);//net::ip::make_address(argv[1]); 
        auto const port = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::atoi(argv[2]));

        net::io_service ios{1};

        tcp::acceptor acceptor{ios, {address, port}};
    
        for (;;)
        {
            tcp::socket socket{ios};

            acceptor.accept(socket);
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Example of error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/beast/core/buffer_traits.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/beast/http/basic_dynamic_body.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/beast/http.hpp:15,
                 from /home/kudryavii/projects/ConsoleChat/ConsoleChat.Server/main.cpp:10:
/usr/local/include/boost/beast/core/detail/buffer_traits.hpp:66:18: error: ‘is_const_buffer_sequence’ is not a member of ‘boost::beast::net’
   66 |             net::is_const_buffer_sequence<B>::value>::type>
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/beast/core/detail/buffer_traits.hpp:66:18: error: ‘is_const_buffer_sequence’ is not a member of ‘boost::beast::net’
```

I tried to add all boost libraries to find package section but this didn't help.

Comment: @Tsyvarev posted first error message.

Comment: Can you provide the precompiled source somewhere? Usually you should be able to get that with `make main.i` (which will output something like `Preprocessing CXX source to CMakeFiles/sotest.dir/main.cpp.i`). Warning file will be large (7.4M herem but only 600k xzipped) but you can probably put it on a pastebin, or even wetransfer. Alternatively you can have a look and see whether you can spot the problem from there yourself

Comment: @sehe I checked CmakeFiles/.dir directory and I couldn't find main.cpp.i. Are you talking about full error message that showed on cmake --build command call due to it's pretty large too?

Comment: I'm not. You have to **explicitly** tell your build tool to make that target, like I said, usually `make main.i` or `ninja main.i` etc.

Comment: Just checked the docs, if you use `cmake --build` you can do `cmake --build . --target main.i`

Comment: @sehe Got it. Uploaded file here: https://filebin.net/ebquhvt5flvz88pi. I tried to understand file by myself but couldn't understand anything...

Comment: Great that repros it. Let me see what I can unearth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. The [preprocessed source](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/21721508-07ae-413f-8b61-e786a6f02d02/main.cpp.i.xz) confirms that the first mention of `is_const_buffer_sequence` is from line 116485 (eek), which is attributed to

```
# 49 "/usr/local/include/boost/beast/core/detail/buffer_traits.hpp" 3
```

from line 116467. On my system, that's not the first mention, because (obviously?)  the declaration in `boost_1_75_0/boost/asio/buffer.hpp` comes before:

```
# 2422 "/home/sehe/custom/boost_1_75_0/boost/asio/buffer.hpp" 2 3 4
```

The include tree for it checks out as¹

```
/usr/include/boost/asio.hpp -->
  /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp -->
    /usr/include/boost/asio/datagram_socket_service.hpp -->
      /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/null_socket_service.hpp -->
        /usr/include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
```

So, let's see if we can trace the similar path for your preprocessed source.

Reducing all the line directives (by stripping actual line numbers, and eliminating subsequent duplicates) I see the expected trail. However, then I spot differences:

```
# 124 "/usr/local/include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp" 3
private:
  friend void* boost::asio::detail::buffer_cast_helper(
      const mutable_buffer& b);
  friend std::size_t boost::asio::detail::buffer_size_helper(
      const mutable_buffer& b);

  void* data_;
  std::size_t size_;
```

Huh? In 1.75.0 these friends don't exist: https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.75.0/include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp

You clearly have something else than Boost 1.75.0 installed there - which is funny because CMake's FindPackage should have complained? Anyways, spelunking some more:

```
git grep -l is_const_buffer_sequence boost-1.{60..75}.0 | grep buffer.hpp
boost-1.66.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.67.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.68.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.69.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.70.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.71.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.72.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.73.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.74.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.75.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
```

And maybe also find out when the friend got deleted:

```
git grep -l friend boost-1.{60..75}.0 | grep buffer.hpp
boost-1.60.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.61.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.62.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.63.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.64.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
boost-1.65.0:include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
```

Right at the same moment. Looks like we can pinpoint an upper-bound to your boost asio header:

```
git log -Sfriend include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp
commit b60e92b13ef68dfbb9af180d76eae41d22e19356
Author: Christopher Kohlhoff <chris@kohlhoff.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 23 14:27:36 2017 +1100

    Initial merge of Networking TS compatibility.
    
    Merged from chriskohlhoff/asio master branch as of commit
    4a4d28b0d24c53236e229bd1b5f378c9964b1ebb.
```

That's the same commit that introduced the `is_const_buffer_sequence`. Git confirms that your Asio version is definitely boost 1.65.0 or older²:

```
git tag --contains b60e92b13ef68dfbb9af180d76eae41d22e19356
boost-1.66.0
boost-1.67.0
boost-1.68.0
boost-1.69.0
boost-1.69.0-beta1
boost-1.70.0
boost-1.70.0.beta1
boost-1.71.0
boost-1.71.0.beta1
boost-1.72.0
boost-1.72.0.beta1
boost-1.73.0
boost-1.73.0.beta1
boost-1.74.0
boost-1.74.0.beta1
boost-1.75.0
boost-1.75.0.beta1
```

> ### Now the wild thing is: Boost Beast didn't exist until Boost 1.66.0

In short, your install is broken. Firstly, you have an old Asio with  newer Beast headers. Secondly, it's installed in such a way that CMake apparently detects it as a valid Boost installation satisfying 1.75.0 required.

---

¹ (this is not 100% full fidelity as I checked using vim's `:check!` command, which doesn't use libclang or anything options/preprocessor aware)

² Of course it will be much easier for you to just look in `/usr/include/boost/version.hpp` or print the value of `BOOST_LIB_VERSION`:

```
std::cout << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << "\n";
```

Comment: Added a non-expiring copy of [main.cpp.i (xz compressed)](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/21721508-07ae-413f-8b61-e786a6f02d02/main.cpp.i.xz)

Comment: Lol, I have boost version 1.61...
Omg, great investigation! Thank you very much!

Comment: Interesting that find_package always says that it found boost 1.75 lib...

Comment: There's more to it. You can't "just" have boost 1.61 because the beast headers couldn't have been there. You have some kind of a mixture. And they're both in /usr/local/include/boost